# On-premise package repository software for Debian

Tags: debian

I'm need to set up an internal debian package repository, and thought I'd see if there are any free, open source alternatives out there. I've used Red Hat Satellite Server (i.e. Spacewalk) in the past, which did a great job of managing packages within different channels (dev, prod, etc). Which products do other Debian user's use for managing internal repos?

Comment: As you still got no answers: did you take a look at the [corresponding Debian document](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup), which lists a couple of candidates (assuming your question is about a repo for Debian packages)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've decided to give Aptly a try. Seems to work pretty well, but I haven't decided on whether to keep it or replace it with another tool .

Comment: As you've tried it and not been disappointed straight away, maybe you want to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) meanwhile? Might prove helpful to others. If you later decide to try another tool, just make that another answer then – and when satisfied, decide which answer to [accept](/help/accepted-answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to give Aplty a try, and it is pretty easy to use once you get a hang of the workflow. My first impression is that it's good tool for more complex setups. As far as I can tell, it's not very suited for simple setups in which on would like local mirrors to be continiously filled with updates from internet repos.